# Vba loop through folders with values

Tags: vba, excel, loops, consolidation

I am a really beginner of vba macro writing and I am facing an issue. I looked up a loop macro which loops the files in one folder and make a consolidated one. The problem is that some of the files have functions so in some columns I am facing reference issue so I would need values instead of the functions. I have been looking for solutions for two days but no progress. I am a trainee at a multinational company and it would make my job easier. Here is my macro:

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("IT&SYS")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()
 Loop

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("Prof Cons")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("Travel")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop


Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("Conference&Entertainment")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("Staff Rel")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("Other")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()

 Loop

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("Facilities&Real Estate")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet7").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you repeating the same blocks over and over? Design intent or?..

Comment: Because every sheet has different name and different kind of data are there. Maybe this is not the best solution but since I am a beginner I did not know anything else.

Comment: To replace the cells that have Formulas with values, use `.Value = .Value`.

Comment: Should I put .Value = .Value before every End With? Or where should I put it/them specifically?

Comment: @BBalint Are those `.xl??` are the same by structure? Do they all have *IT&SYS*, *Prof Cons* etc worksheets? Is needed information always located in `$B$1:$AI$Rows`?

Comment: @AntiDrondert yes, exactly. the macro works I have only problems with pasting the formulas in instead of values. Because when the macro inserting in the formulas on some sheets it says reference problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answers . I made up my version with the "two row" solution I have been trying this one but in different forms so that is why it did not work but thanknyou all for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do your `.Copy` and `.Paste` in two lines instead of one:

```
With Worksheets("Travel")
    Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
    Rng.Copy 
    Wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End With
```

Also, agreeing with everyone that one loop would be best here, dealing with each worksheet inside that loop.

Something like:

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("IT&SYS")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy 
        Wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        
    End With
    With Worksheets("Prof Cons")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy 
        Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues       
    End With
    With Worksheets("Travel")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        
    End With
    With Worksheets("Conference&Entertainment")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy 
        Wb.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        
    End With
    With Worksheets("Staff Rel")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy 
        Wb.Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        
    End With
    With Worksheets("Other")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy 
        Wb.Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues       
    End With
    With Worksheets("Facilities&Real Estate")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        Rng.Copy 
        Wb.Worksheets("Sheet7").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)       
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    MyFile = Dir()
 Loop




End Sub
```

This could still be cleaned up since there is a lot of copy/paste code in here, but this will be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your repeating block can be a separate procedure you can call with different parameters.
Note that you loop through files several times.
Do not use copy at all, instead transfer range values.
How I would do that:

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()
    Dim MyFile As String, MyDir As String ',Str As String <- not used
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    MyDir = "D:\PersonalData\BodaBali\Desktop\vba loop\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xl??")
    ChDir MyDir
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
        HelpSub Wb.Worksheets("Prof Cons"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        HelpSub Wb.Worksheets("IT&SYS"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        HelpSub Wb.Worksheets("Travel"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        HelpSub Wb.Worksheets("Conference&Entertainment"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        HelpSub Wb.Worksheets("Staff Rel"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")
        HelpSub Wb.Worksheets("Other"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")
        Wb.Close False
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub HelpSub(wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestination As Worksheet)
    Dim Rng As Range, Rws As Long
    With wsSource
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 35), .Cells(Rws, 2))
        wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp). _
            Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value
    End With
End Sub
```